# How do I divide values that are in the same column based on an ID column?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to create a column on a Power BI table that divides values from one column based on an ID column which IDs that I specify

I understand that I need to loop through the column twice but I am kind of confused about how to do that. I have used the function `LOOKUPVALUE` but I keep getting an error. Below is the code that I am working on:

```
Answer =
OR(
IF (
    Table[ID] = 11,
    Table[Q] / LOOKUPVALUE ( Table[Q], Table[ID], 1 ),
    IF (
        Table[ID] = 12,
        Table[Q] / LOOKUPVALUE ( Table[Q], Table[ID], 2 ),
        IF ( Table[ID] = 13, Table[Q] / LOOKUPVALUE ( Table[Q], Table[ID], 3 ) )
    )
),IF ( Table[ID] = 31, Table[Q] / LOOKUPVALUE ( Table[Q], Table[ID], 1 ) )
    )
),IF ( Table[ID] = 32, Table[Q] / LOOKUPVALUE ( Table[Q], Table[ID], 2 ) )
    )
),IF ( Table[ID] = 33, Table[Q] / LOOKUPVALUE ( Table[Q], Table[ID], 3 ) )
    )
),IF ( Table[ID] = 51, Table[Q] / LOOKUPVALUE ( Table[Q], Table[ID], 1 ) )
    )
),IF ( Table[ID] = 52, Table[Q] / LOOKUPVALUE ( Table[Q], Table[ID], 2 ) )
    )
),IF ( Table[ID] = 53, Table[Q] / LOOKUPVALUE ( Table[Q], Table[ID], 3 ) )
    )
),0)
```

Below is a demonstration on what I want to accomplish

[image]

*Example table has been edited*

Answer (score 0):

It's rather odd to have those first three rows in the same table as the rest, but I think something like this might work for you:

```
Answer = Table[Q] / LOOKUPVALUE ( Table[Q], Table[ID], MOD ( Table[ID], 10 ) )
```

This divides `Q` by the value corresponding to the lookup on the last digit.

---

**Edit:**

If you are wanting to specify ID matchings explicitly, then I'd recommend using a `SWITCH` rather than a bunch of nested `IF` functions.

For example,

```
Answer =
SWITCH (
    Table[ID],
    11, Table[Q] / LOOKUPVALUE ( Table[Q], Table[ID], 1 ),
    12, Table[Q] / LOOKUPVALUE ( Table[Q], Table[ID], 2 ),
    13, Table[Q] / LOOKUPVALUE ( Table[Q], Table[ID], 3 ),
    31, Table[Q] / LOOKUPVALUE ( Table[Q], Table[ID], 1 ),
    32, Table[Q] / LOOKUPVALUE ( Table[Q], Table[ID], 2 ),
    33, Table[Q] / LOOKUPVALUE ( Table[Q], Table[ID], 3 ),
    51, Table[Q] / LOOKUPVALUE ( Table[Q], Table[ID], 1 ),
    52, Table[Q] / LOOKUPVALUE ( Table[Q], Table[ID], 2 ),
    53, Table[Q] / LOOKUPVALUE ( Table[Q], Table[ID], 3 )
)
```

Or more compactly,

```
Answer =
VAR LookupID =
    SWITCH (
        TRUE (),
        Table[ID] IN { 11, 31, 51 }, 1,
        Table[ID] IN { 12, 32, 52 }, 2,
        Table[ID] IN { 13, 33, 53 }, 3
    )
RETURN
    Table[Q] / LOOKUPVALUE ( Table[Q], Table[ID], LookupID )
```

Please see this reference for detail on the `SWITCH(TRUE(),...)` construction:

[DAX – The Diabolical Genius of “SWITCH TRUE”](https://powerpivotpro.com/2015/03/the-diabolical-genius-of-switch-true/)

Comment: That works for this particle example but I have a table with thousands of rows and I only care about about a set category to divide by. For example the miles, Km, Feet,Inches, are mixed with other categories such as Misc,Count, Average. I don't want to have misc, count and Average to be apart of the calculation. that's why the first 3 rows are equal to zero. I don't want hours to be apart of the ratio

Comment: Can you provide additional details in the question then? I can only answer based on what I see in the question.

Comment: I recreated the example to focus on what I am trying to do. Say I only care about Ids 11,12,13,31,32,33,51,52,53 and I want to divide it by Ids 1,2,3.